# How do photons give atoms more heat energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, visible-light, temperature

this is a duplicate [of this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83041/) 
but I came away not understanding the answer, even after reading the links.

so my question is: how does light increase the heat energy of an atom?

**eg.** if you have a lens and you focus a lot of light into a point you can get a fire, what is the science behind the fire-from-light part of this

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  You state Kinetic Energy in the title but Heat Energy in the text.  Are you asking about heating up a large collection of atoms or imparting kinetic energy to a single particle at the quantum level?

Comment: @Ryan Bright The answer to the question for which yours is a duplicate,  is very clear. There is no single dominant mechanism which transfers the energy of a photon absorbed by a single atom into its kinetic energy.

Comment: @ggcg sorry I mean heat energy, I will edit

Comment: @DrSTLakshmikumar, you say there is no single dominant mechanism...  But it is worth documenting the mechanisms and explaining them.  Certainly there is some mechanism at work, scattering, etc.

Comment: @ggcg the answer given to the "duplicate" question is quite comprehensive. I saw no reason to copy or paraphrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Light is an electromagnetic wave, which you can think of as vibrations in the electromagnetic field in space. When a vibrating electric field reaches a charged particle, such as those in an atom, it exerts back-and-forth forces on the particles, causing them to move and oscillate repeatedly at the frequency of the light. This movement is kinetic energy. An increase in the collective kinetic energy of molecules corresponds to increased temperature, and given a sufficiently large increase, you can create a fire under usual conditions.